# Which are the options to store data from a mobile app? Firebase?

Tags: firebase, flutter

I need create a android app with simple forms for a survey and the data need to be stored for posterior analysis.

I need sugestions about what I could use.

One question about is: Can I develop the mobile app in Flutter and use Firebase as storage to the database?

It's a small app, so the free tier of firebase can works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can. And it will help you to realize features like "only submit once" and "edit data post submit".

Alternatively, you can use any kind of backend server (even a simple web server with php) as an endpoint for Flutter. Maybe even a simple backend service that sends you the form data as an email.